# CSS Template Code Reading

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying to read the code that comes with the default ASP.NET MVC 4 project template. I can't figure out what code generates the little black bar that goes across the top of the page. In the HTML page there doesn't appear to be any HTML code to do it, and I can't find any margins or padding in the uppermost sections of the page that would create it.

The CSS code:
http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=8DdpK

The .cshtml file that defines the layout:
http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=LCrA7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `border-top` for `body` adds the black bar at the top of the page:

```css
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000; /* <-- This adds the border to the top of the page */
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: dang how did I miss that. Thank you.